# React Redux- Cant initial a variable in the function of map of List

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react component which containing a Tab ,
i want to load the tab items into the Tab dynamically with 
a Div , **the problem is i cant assign a id to every Div**
for example id=**divPage1react** , id=**divPage2react** , id=**divPage3react** ...

**It shows Uncaught SyntaxError on  var id="divPage"+index+"react";**

i think its inside the render so i cant initial a variable in the function of  map of List . Anyone can help? thx

```
var tabs = [
            { 'id': 1 ,'content': 1 ,'title': '1'},
            { 'id': 2 ,'content': 2 ,'title': '2'}
         ];



  class ControlledTabs extends React.Component {
          constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context);

          }
          render() {

          const { tabs } = this.props;      
          const listTab = tabs.map((tab,index) => (

                  var id="divPage"+index+"react";  

                  <Tab  eventKey={tab.id}   title={tab.title} key={tab.id}>
                  { <div>
                      <div id=id></div>
                  </div>

                  }
                  </Tab>  
                  ))

        return (
          <Tabs>
           {listTab}
          </Tabs>
        );
      }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rewrite your problematic `div` inside your `listTab`-function as:

```
<div>
  <div id={id}></div>
</div>
```

The whole function should look like:

```
const listTab = tabs.map((tab,index) => {
    const id="divPage"+index+"react";  
    return (
        <Tab  eventKey={tab.id}   title={tab.title} key={tab.id}>
            <div>
                <div id={id}></div>
            </div>
        </Tab>  
   );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use need to use an explicit return syntax within the map function instead of an implicit return

```
const listTab = tabs.map((tab,index) => { // note the use of curly braces

    var id="divPage"+index+"react";  
    // using an explicit return here
    return (
          <Tab  eventKey={tab.id}   title={tab.title} key={tab.id}>
               {<div>
                      <div id={id}></div>
                </div>}
           </Tab>  
     )
})
```

Comment: You are still going to get an error on `<div id=id>`. The value is missing curly braces.

Comment: @CarlosC, Updated my answer, I missed that part since the original error was because of implicit return in map